# How to calculate the sum of array inside hash ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

Hai i am creating a json file with my data and i need to calculate the hours before i save it into the database

I am assigning that hash into a variable payload and tried doing this but it returns me an error TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):

```
total_hours = @payload.sum{|activity| activity[:hours].to_f}
```

*Hash before converting to json*

```
{:activities=>
  [{:project=>1,
    :activity=>"my activity",
    :hours=>0.2e1,
    :date=>Sat, 10 Aug 2019 00:00:00 UTC +00:00},
   {:project=>2,
    :activity=>"Tester",
    :hours=>0.2e1,
    :date=>Thu, 01 Aug 2019 00:00:00 UTC +00:00},
   {:project=>2,
    :activity=>"Tester",
    :hours=>0.3e1,
    :date=>Thu, 01 Aug 2019 00:00:00 UTC +00:00}]}
```

I need to sum the hours of my array which is inside the hash. Thanks

Comment: Try `total_hours = @payload[:activities].sum{|activity| activity[:hours].to_f}`

Comment: @jvillian Thank you so much it worked!! Can you say what was i doing wrong

Comment: Yes, adding as an answer right now.

Comment: You have targeted object instead of array. thats the reason `[:activities]` is array of obj.

Comment: Oh my bad, Thank you. Can you add this as an answer so i can choose it as my answer so it would be helpful to others too.

Comment: `@payload` is an object (an instance of the class `Hash`, which is also an object). `@payload[:activities]` is also an object (an instance of the class `Array`, which is also an object). And, each element of `@payload[:activities]` is also an object (each an instance of the class `Hash`). In Rubyland, everything is an object. So, it's not about "targeting object instead of array", really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
total_hours = @payload[:activities].sum{|activity| activity[:hours].to_f}
```

You see, what you're wanting to do is, essentially:

```
[
  {
    :project=>1,
    :activity=>"my activity",
    :hours=>0.2e1,
    :date=>Sat, 10 Aug 2019 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
  },
  {
    :project=>2,
    :activity=>"Tester",
    :hours=>0.2e1,
    :date=>Thu, 01 Aug 2019 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
  },
  {
    :project=>2,
    :activity=>"Tester",
    :hours=>0.3e1,
    :date=>Thu, 01 Aug 2019 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
  }
].sum{|activity| activity[:hours].to_f}
```

But, you're calling `.sum` on the `@payload` variable, which is a hash. What you want is the value of the hash that is associated with the key `:activities`. Thus, you need to call `.sum` on `@payload[:activities]` where `@payload[:activities]` returns the array above.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Rails, here is a short way:

```
@payload[:activities].pluck(:hours).reduce(:+)
```

Comment: `@payload[:activities].sum(:hours)` will work and is shorter.

Comment: No, you'll have an undefined method + for :hours Symbol. Check it.